'new' keyword returning the same instance of a class
I have these two classes, one inheriting from the other.
When an external script calls .copy(), it always receives a parent DataComponent, never a BooleanProperty.
If copy() isn't called, a pass-by-reference is obtained instead, causing changes to one instance to affect another one (because they're the same; I don't want this);
I believe this is a me-problem not knowing the syntax of the language or something, hopefully it's just that.
Using Unity 2020.3.17f1 with Windows 10.
Code of the two classes:
[System.Serializable]
public class DataComponent
{
    public DataComponent(string n = "")
    {
        name = n;
    }

    public string name;
    [System.NonSerialized]public string value;

    public DataComponent copy()
    {
        DataComponent ret = new DataComponent(this.name);
        ret.value = this.value;
        return ret;
    }
}

[System.Serializable]
public class BooleanProperty : DataComponent
{
    public BooleanProperty(string n = "") : base(n) { }

    public new bool value;

    public new BooleanProperty copy()
    {
        BooleanProperty ret = new BooleanProperty(name);
        ret.value = value;
        return ret;
    }
}

-The problem was solved by declaring a separate copyBool() method inside BooleanProperty. Calling copyBool() works as expected (returns a new instance)

What does "always receives a parent DataComponent" mean? I suspect that the issue lies with your usage of public new BooleanProperty copy() - which is a common case of using the new specifier wrong

@UnholySheep It means, when I see it in the editor, I see a name and no value (the string in the base class is purposefully hidden to point out such errors). I do not see the checkbox I expect to see.

As far as I know (not enough clearly :/ ) using 'new' on a method hides the inherited one so that childClass.method() calls the child's method of that name and not the parent's one.

" so that childClass.method() calls the child's method of that name and not the parent's one" - only if the variable is declared to be of the child type. If you have DataComponent comp = new BooleanProperty(); var copy = comp.copy(); then it will call the implementation in DataComponent.

Considering you can change both classes, this can be solved by making the copy of the base class virtual and the copy of the child class override instead of new.

The use of new like this is a red flag that you're using inheritance incorrectly. You have two classes that need to implement the same functions and be used interchangeably. This sounds like an interface.

public interface IComponent
{
    IComponent Copy();
}
public class DataComponent : IComponent
{
    public string Value { get; set; } = "";
    public IComponent Copy()
    {
        return new DataComponent { Value = Value };
    }
}
public class BooleanComponent : IComponent
{
    public bool Value { get; set; }
    public IComponent Copy()
    {
        return new BooleanComponent { Value = Value };
    }
}

If you have other requirements that mean you need to inherit BooleanComponent from DataComponent you could do that, making Copy virtual and still returning an IComponent.

Exactly. Inheritance means that the derived class IS the same as the parent, just an "evolved" version. You can not exchange or remove anything the base class has. So when the two classes are fundamentally different when it comes to actual data fields, they should not be based on each other. Having a common interface usually makes more sense. Serialization is a completely different beast, especially in Unity

This is because you have used new keyword to override method, instead of override. With new keyword, you just hide base implementation and when the variable is used as the base type, base implementation will com einto play. Also, copy method should be virtual in DataComponent
Consider this simple scenario:
public class Base
{
    public virtual void Method()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am Base");
    }
}

public class Derived : Base 
{
    public override void Method()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am Dervied");
    }
}

public class DerivedWithNew : Base
{
    public new void Method()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am Dervied");
    }
}

and the program:
var derived = new Derived();
derived.Method(); // I am Dervied
((Base)derived).Method(); // I am Dervied

var derivedWithNew = new DerivedWithNew();
derivedWithNew.Method(); // I am Dervied
((Base)derivedWithNew).Method(); // I am Base <--!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!


Alright, thanks for the tip! I'll avoid using 'new' like this; as stated, they need different return types so I can't quite do this, but thank you anyways

They don't need different return types, you can return a BooleanComponent as a DataComponent.

The inheritance in the OP just makes no sense as you can not change the type of a field in a derived type. The derived type will always have the fields of the base class. So inheritance didn't make sense in the first place the way it was used. Type-safety and abstraction goes a bit against each other.
